# What is the status of Ubuntu Mobile? Is the project expected to reinitiate in coming years?

Tags: android, ubuntu-for-android

With android and Google Play becoming so popular, it would be great to have Ubuntu on mobile devices again.

Some archaic references:

http://blog.canonical.com/2008/06/24/ubuntu-mid-edition-804-achieves-its-first-public-release/

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MobileTeam/Mobile?action=show&redirect=MobileAndEmbedded

Answer (score 0):

There is a Ubuntu only device on the market :)
`http://www.bq.com/gb/ubuntu.html`
It doesn't have Google Play, but has plenty of applications available and more are coming.